# How to reuse a property as a class in OWL?

Tags: rdf, owl, protege, rdfs

I am developing an ontology in OWL given a diagram and the diagram shows that a property between two classes is also a class that has other relationships with different classes. Like, there is a dotted line in the diagram indicating this relationship between a property and the class. Can someone please show me some reference on what this is? Thanks in advance.

Example: *"A"* is the *"intention"* of *"B"* but *"intention"* is also a subclass of *"thoughts"* and has a relationship with *"philanthropy"*.

Comment: without seeing the diagram, impossible. Other than that, you can use the same URI for both, class and property. That's called "punning" in OWL 2.

Comment: Predicates in RDF are not full instances, so a specific use of a property does not create an instance of its corresponding class and cannot be described further. As mentioned, OWL 2 makes it possible to use context to determine whether a specific resource acts as an individual, property or class, so it's possible to use one for all, but there's no logical link. In your case, it seems better to distinguish between `:intention` (intending something) and `:Intention` (describing the intention itself).